# How to push new objectId in array of a objectIds inside a document using FindOneAndUpdate query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user schema which has orders array :

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.schema({
    name : String , email :String,
    orders : [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref :'Orders' }]
})
```

what I want to do is to push a new OrderId into user's orders using findOneAndUpdate query

```
const newUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate( myUserId ,
{ 'orders' : {$push  : newOrderId}  } ,
{new:true , runValidators : true })
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: What happens if you remove the third param? This part: `{new:true , runValidators : true }`

Comment: If we remove the 3rd paramater , then the updated document will NOT be returned and old document will be returned by the query . I uses { new : true} to get updated document and then returns it in the response